# what is the best way to get other class of object reference??

Tags: java

Sorry, i can't give better title.I have two class A and B.A class is singleton class.it always gives same object to whoever want it.Here B class always want that A object refenence. check follow code

```
class B
{
    private A a;
    B(){
      this.a=A.getAObject();
    }
    public void process(String[] args) 
    {
        a.sendData();//line 1
         (or)
        A.getAObject().sendData();//line 2
    }
}
```

which is best way as mentioned above line 1 or line 2 as performance wise like that??

Comment: line 2. And remove the `this.a=A.getAObject();` as `class A` is singleton object. You always need to access `A`'s object by calling static method!

Comment: This really doesn't make a difference, except perhaps for unit tests or readability.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases the differences will be insignificant.

But there would be scenarios like where you have to create a lot of instances of `B`. So in those scenarios there would be a performance impact since introducing a filed to that class means taking more memory when creating a instance.

If it is not a scenario like that, I think its better to assign it to a variable, since it will improve the readability of the code if you use that instance often in the class.

Comment: No, introducing a field in class B means that every instance will take more memory. If there are lots of instances of B, that could have a very serious impact. There's really no point in having a copy of the same value in every object of type B.

Comment: @JonSkeet He is asking about performance wise. And you are answering about a specific scenario where a lot of Objects of B can created. I was answering generally :)

Comment: Memory is part of performance - even in terms of execution time, as the more memory that is taken, the less effective the memory caches will be. I fail to see how "if you have to use the methods and variables in A class a lot" is general but "if there are lots of instances of B" is specific. Besides, making a *general* claim for something that fails to include a specific but entirely reasonable scenario isn't great either. The performance of the two options simply isn't the same.

Comment: "Both will be same is the general" part. and the difference between the part you highlighted in mine and yours is "if". performance of the two options simply isn't the same for your scenario. True

Comment: @JonSkeet Since I can't edit the last comment, You are saying No, based on your scenario and I'm not saying "Both will be same" based on my scenario you have highlighted. I have mentioned my scenario to just give an extra info about the readability :)

Comment: "Both will be same" is still incorrect in the general case though. Why would you assume that memory consumption is generally irrelevant? Would you make the same claim about a class with (say) a thousand fields - that it performs the same as a class with zero fields? You could reasonably say that in many cases (ideally providing more information about those cases) the differences will be insignificant, but that's *very* different from saying the performance is "the same".

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree with you about the last part. Its true. And I have edited my answer

Comment: Okay, that's better. (I'm still not sure I agree in terms of readability, but that's definitely subjective.)

Comment: @JonSkeet and Sand . Thanks bro ,though i got negative vote for this question that i dont know why??,but you answered me.

Answer (score 1):

**You can reference of one class to another class by making reference of the other class**

In your code you do something like this :

```
  class B {
         private A a;
        B(A a){
        this.a=a; //refernce of a
    }
        public void display(){
       a.getA(); //display method of a 
    }

        }
    class A{
    public void getA(){
    ....
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it's answering the question asked. The OP wants to get at the singleton A from B, not vice versa.